# Docker - Adding new Wordpress container to existing SQL database container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to understand or find information on how I would connect a new Wordpress container to an existing MariaDB container. I'm missing something. I can add a Wordpress instance while also creating the MariaDB container. See below.

````
services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8282:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db:db

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    environment: 
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
    

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
  phpmyadmin:```

After that has spun up and is good to go, I then attempt another docker-compose.yml (see below) and I cannot get the Wordpress instance to connect to the SQL instance.

```version: '3.7'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    container_name: wordup
    ports:
      - 8283:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 172.20.0.3
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: username
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wp2
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    
volumes:
  wp2:
````

How would I point the new WP instance to the database that I created on the MariaDB container?  Is it possible to point new Docker Compose stacks to an already created DB without recreating a new DB?  I know that it's not a good idea to share DB's across different applications, but I have a need to pull in data from one Wordpress site to another.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to run two deployments by two `docker-compose.yml` files and make one `docker-compose` connect to other? Did I get it right?

Comment: @geobreze Yes, I may have differe docker-compose files for different services (think Wordpress) but I may want to share a database (container) that was generated using another docker-compose file.  I cannot figure out to reference that already created DB within a docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker networks. You need to connect two docker-compose files to the same network and inside this network containers can reference each other by container name.

Here is more information about docker-compose networking in the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

Take a look at an example with two Nginx proxies that started using different docker-compose files. The first proxy redirects to the second one and then it redirects us to `google.com`.

First proxy `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    first:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        networks:
            - "test-network"
networks:
    test-network:
        name: "test-network"
        driver: "bridge"
```

First proxy `ngnix.conf`

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://second:80; # in second docker-compose file we're setting container_name to "second", thus we can reference second container by this name
        }
    }
}
```

Second proxy `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    second:
        container_name: "second" # note, that we don't need to expose ports because we don't need to make this service visible to a host. But it's not restricted to expose ports. You can do so if you need.
        build: .
        networks:
            - "test-network"
networks:
    test-network:
        name: "test-network"
        driver: "bridge"
```

Second proxy `ngnix.conf`:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://google.com;
        }
    }
}
```